# Do you need a negative covid test result to fly within Colombia?

Tags: covid-19

Do people flying within Colombia need to show a negative covid test result?

Answer (score 2):

Not for domestic travel at present. No tests or even vaccinations required as of July. Most recent government regulations as of this writing are [here- in Spanish](https://www.minsalud.gov.co/Normatividad_Nuevo/Resoluci%C3%B3n%20No.%201238%20de%202022.pdf).

International arrivals do require RA or PCR tests within specified time windows, or fully vaccinated status (might depend on the origin, best to check that).

---

For example, [LATAM airline](https://www.latamairlines.com/ca/en/experience/coronavirus/restrictions) says the following:

[image]

Of course regulations could be tightened in the future and individual entities could impose more restrictive rules most likely.